# Degeneration of transcendence degree in polynomial rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, transcendence-degree

Before ask the general question, let us check the motivating example.

Consider two transcendental elements (and they are algebraically independent) over $\mathbb C$, say $x$ and $y$. Then $\mathbb C[x,y]$ has transcendence degree 2 over $\mathbb C$. Now take subrings. One thing is

$$\mathbb C[x,y^2-x]$$

and another one is

$$\mathbb C[x+y,(x+y)^2].$$

The first one has transcendence degree 2 over $\mathbb C$, but the second one has degree 1 obviously.

So in general setting, consider a subring $A=k[y_1,\ldots,y_d]$ in $k[x_1,\ldots,k_d]$. Thus $y_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq d$ is a polynomial over $k$ with variables $x_1,\ldots,x_d$. How we determine that $A$ has transcendence degree $d$, or $<d$.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the transcendence degree is only defined for field extensions. So it is $k(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ that has transcendence degree $n$ over  $k$, where $k$ is any field. And not the polynomial ring. What do you mean by the transcendence degree of a ring extension?

Comment: Right. But if $R $ is an integral domain, we define its transcendence degree using its field of fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B = k[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$ a polynomial ring and $y_i \in B$ for $i=1,\ldots,d$ and $A=k[y_1,\ldots,y_d]$. Consider the exact sequence

$$0 \to I \to k[W_1,\ldots,W_d] = C \xrightarrow{\phi} B$$

with $\phi(W_\nu) = y_\nu$. The ideal $I$ can be easily computed in a concrete example e.g. with Macaulay2. This is nothing more but a suitable gröbner base calculation. Iff $I=0$ then $\mathrm{trdeg}_k A = d$.

More generally $\mathrm{trdeg}_k A = \dim A = \dim C/I$ as $A = \phi(C) \cong C/I$ and $\dim C/I$ can be computed with Macaulay2 too - in general it can be read off from the leading terms of a gröbner base of $I$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a question, maybe a basic one. Could you explain ' in general it can be read off from the leading terms of a gröbner base of $I$.'? How we compute the dimension of $C/I$ using a Groebner base of $I$? Could you recommand any reference for it?

Comment: I suggest, to read Cox, Little, O'Shea "Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms", Chapter 9. It explains the necessary concepts very thoroughly. The idea is to find (in the example above) the monomials $W_1^{e_1} \cdot \cdots \cdot W_d^{e_d}$ which are not in the lead monomial ideal associated to (a grevlex grobner base of) the ideal $I$. If $h$ is the dimension of $C/I$ then the number of such monomials with $e_1+\cdots + e_d <= e$ grows as $c e^h + O(e^{h-1})$ for a certain rational $c$. Look also for the term "Hilbert function" in other books of your choice.

Comment: For a deeper understanding of the possibilities and techniques of using gröbner bases in commutative algebra, I recommend Greuel, Pfister "A Singular Introduction to Commutative Algebra"

Comment: Thank you Boehm.